# How to check if an element in an array exists in another array

Tags: ruby, string, jruby

I have two different arrays of strings, `array1` and `array2`, in which I want to find out if the elements in `array1` also exist in `array2` without modifying the elements in `array1`, but the values in `array1` include the extra characters including and after the colon `:`.

```
array1 = ["unit 1 : Unit 1","unit 2 : Unit 2","unit 3 : Unit 3","test : Test", "system1"]
array2 = ["unit 1","unit 2","unit 3","test"]
```

I tried using  `include?` but it doesn't work.

```
array1.each do |element|
    #see if element exists in array 2
    if array2.include? element
         #print the name of that element
         puts element
    end
end
```

How would I approach this?

Comment: Please edit to show the desired result for your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing your approach, you could split the `element` with `space`+`:`+`space` and get the `first` chunk for the check. Instead of `if array2.include? element` use

```
if array2.include? element.split(' : ').first
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/yZxuCf)

Comment: This does not modify the elments in array1 does it? If not, this works just fine! Thank you

Comment: Sure, the array remains unchanged. The `element` is a copy of the real array element in this case, see http://ideone.com/msEgJV

Answer (score 2):

```
# Gather the prefixes from array1, without modifying array1:
array1_prefixes = array1.map { |s| s.split(" : ").first }

# Figure out which elements array1 and array2 have in common
common_elements = array1_prefixes & array2
# => ["unit 1", "unit 2", "unit 3", "test"]
```

This solution relies on the [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Array.html#method-i-26) operator, which performs set intersection.

Comment: Perhaps `"unit 1    :Unit 1".split(/\s*:\s*/) #=> ["unit 1", "Unit 1"]` in case there is not exactly one space on each side of the colon (if that behaviour is desired by the asker). Alternatively, `"unit 1   : Unit 1"[/.*?(?=\s*:)/] #=> "unit 1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most readable method to use here might be `startwith?`, but if you know a key cannot be a substring of another key.

To see if all keys are in place:

```
array2.all? do |item|
  array1.any?{|keyval| keyval.startwith? item }
end
```